# Output an array's contents as Hyperlinks to a cell

Tags: vba

Suppose the array is from 0 to 2 (but will not always be). Under different circumstances the size is expected to change. Furthermore the info is grouped into 3 elements, the 1rst element is the cell address, the second element is the sheet name the cell was found in, and the 3rd element is the workbook name. I want the rest of the output to follow down the same column, which would be A, so I guess column 0. Btw I want this as a Function and not as a subroutine, because i am passing the array in.

Also here was my attempt to write a function to output the hyperlink to a new sheet at cell A1

```
Private Function DisplayResults(cellAddressArr As Variant)

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim s As String
Dim Value As String
Dim c As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Set WS = Sheets.Add
WS.Range("A1") = "Cell location"

j = 0
i = 0

Do
    'the WS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor line is incorrectly formatted, or something is
    'entirely wrong with my logic behind outputting my array...  
    WS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WS.Range("A & j + 2"), Address:="labInventory" & "\" &
    cellAddressArr(i + 2), SubAddress:=cellAddressArr(i + 1) & "!" & cellAddressArr(i), 
    TextToDisplay:="Link"
    i = 1 + 3
    j = j + 1
Loop While i <> UBound(cellAddressArr)
End Function
```

http://gyazo.com/0cf8adc013f0d5c8137586162e431b3b, this is an example of the array's contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing :

```
WS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WS.Range("A & j + 2"), Address:="labInventory" & "\" &
    cellAddressArr(i + 2), SubAddress:=cellAddressArr(i + 1) & "!" & cellAddressArr(i), 
    TextToDisplay:="Link"
```

to :

```
WS.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WS.Range("A" & j + 2), Address:="labInventory" & "\" &
    cellAddressArr(i + 2), SubAddress:=cellAddressArr(i + 1) & "!" & cellAddressArr(i), 
    TextToDisplay:="Link"
```

:)

Comment: Thank you very much, that should be the solution to the problem, how do I "reward" you or tag you as the right answer? Also f you don't mind a different error came up, and apparently my "Subscript is out of range".... Edit: nvm I just gave you the checkmark :)

Comment: yup, stupidest error ever, I failed to realize that one I needed an If Else statement for this case scenario because if I incremented i = i + 3, then that would lead to an error, because it would go over the range, so I needed a case for the smallest array possible which would be size 3. Also for some reason changing my counters i and j to Integer solved the problem... Idk why I can't use long, but i'm not sure if curious enough to research LOL, it would be nice to know tho...

Comment: Can't explain why changing TO `Integer` fixed the problem. More often than not, the opposite is true; `Integer` is a 16-bit-long field, whereas `Long` is 32-bit-long (which means it can go up to 2,147,483,648 instead of being limited to 32,768)

Comment: Yeah that was my thought process too, but honestly it might not even be that it was because I changed to Integer, I believe that it was because I introduced the If Else statement

Comment: Anyways glad to have finally gotten the final function out of the way in my program, and YAY it finally works, probably still neeeds more debugging, and several throw error statements for the loops, but whew it's nice to finally see something work. :D

Comment: Superb! Glad I could help :D